# The value of $i^{-39}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have tried to solve the problem in the following way:

$$i^{-39} = 1/i^{39} = i^{4\cdot 9+3} = 1/(-i) = -i$$

However the answer is supposed to be $i$

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: please type in mathjax. Also, $1/(-i)=i$ (further, an intermediate step was typed incorrectly but I did not fix it)

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is as follows:
$$i^{-39} = \frac{1}{i^{39}} = i^{4\cdot9 + 3} = \frac{1}{-i} = -i.$$

I think the second and last equations should be
$$\frac{1}{i^{39}} = \frac{1}{i^{4\cdot9 + 3}} = \frac{1}{-i} = i,$$
since $-i^2 = -(-1) = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Your very last step was incorrect.
$$
\frac{1}{-i}\neq -i
$$
Instead, try "multiplying by 1"...
$$
\frac{1}{-i}\cdot \Big(1\Big)=\frac{1}{-i}\cdot\Big(\frac{i}{i}\Big)=\frac{i}{-i^2}=\frac{i}{1}=i
$$